# how to use callback functions with object/method pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, callable

I have a simple method which accepts a function to call this back later:

```
def SimpleFunc(parm1):
    print(parm1)

class CallMe:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def Call(self, parm):
        self.func(parm)

caller = CallMe(SimpleFunc)
caller.Call("Hallo")
```

That works fine!

But I want to use a class method and want to call the method on a defined object as callback:

```
class WithClassMethod:
    def __init__( self, val ):
        self.val = val 

    def Func(self, parm):
        print( "WithClass: ", self.val, parm )


obj = WithClassMethod(1)
caller = CallMe( ??? )
caller.Call("Next")
```

How can I bind an object/method pair to a callable object?

Attention: The code from `CallMe` is not under my control. It comes from a webserver which needs a handler function.

Comment: just `caller = CallMe(obj.Func)` if I'm not misunderstanding things?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard: Ubs. I am new to python and come from c++ so I search for more difficult solutions :-) make it an answer so I can accept. Thanks!

Comment: Done, I added a bit more information to it too if interested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could simply pass the method object to the class:

```
called = CallMe(obj.Func)
```

To expand a bit, instance methods are really just the original class function:

```
>>> obj.Func.__func__
<function __main__.WithClassMethod.Func>
```

which, during access on an instance (`obj.Func`) are transformed via a descriptor (`__get__`) that attaches `self` (the instance) to them:

```
>>> obj.Func.__self__
<__main__.WithClassMethod at 0x7fbe740ce588>
```

so you can pretty much do anything you want with methods as with functions.

Comment: Ah, I see. Coming from a JavaScript background, I expected `self` to be bound on call, not on get. That's very interesting :)